# Can kio-gdrive be installed to Kubuntu, or only KDE Neon?

Tags: kubuntu, kde, google-drive

Having read [this article](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2017/05/kde-google-drive-integration-in-plasma) I have been trying to install kio-gdrive 1.2 to Kubuntu 17.04. I previously installed kaccounts-provider without issue.

I then downloaded the .tar.xz of v1.1.80 from t[he link provided](https://download.kde.org/unstable/kio-gdrive/1.1.80/src/) and followed the instructions from README.md. I immediately ran into the KF5I18n and KF5KIO problems exactly as detailed in [this unresolved reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/kde/comments/55njaw/need_help_installing_kio_gdrive/). Note that I also tried installing from a newer version of the .tar.gz of v1.1.90, which I guess only became available after the article was written, and also from the cloned git repository, with the exact same results. I also uninstalled and reinstalled kio, which did not go well, but I think I'm all better now.

I was eventually able to overcome these problems by following the Debian/Kubuntu instructions for [KStars](https://techbase.kde.org/Projects/Edu/KStars/Building_KStars_KF5) which also has these packages as dependencies. But now I have an exactly similar problem, but with a different package: KPimGAPI. Google isn't helping much this time.

My best guess ATM is kio-gdrive can only be installed if one is running proper KDE Neon. If that's right, then I'm ready to give up after reading the [Neon FAQ](https://neon.kde.org/faq), unless anyone wants to persuade me that I am at least no worse off with it than Kubuntu - my impression is that I would be. If I read the runes correctly then simply adding the Neon repository just seems like making a rod for my own back.

Comment: KUbuntu 18.04.1 I did not have to install anything. Went to `Online Accounts` and logged in to google. The google drive was in `Networks`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up installing `google-drive-ocamlfuse`. With it you can "mount" a "Google Drive" to a folder.

I executed:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:alessandro-strada/ppa
sudo apt update && sudo apt install google-drive-ocamlfuse
mkdir ~/gdrive
google-drive-ocamlfuse ~/gdrive
```

That way you can use e.g. advanced interactive synchronizers, like the one included in Krusader:

[image]

Finally, in order to "unmount":

```
fusermount -u ~/gdrive
```

There is more information in [this OMG! Ubuntu article](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2017/04/mount-google-drive-ocamlfuse-linux).

Comment: This all seems to have worked perfectly, thank you very much - upvoted and approved.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, I've just done it on 17.10, using the PPA below.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kubuntu-ppa/backports
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install kio-gdrive
```

Update your system with latest fixes:

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Then, go to System Settings -> Online Accounts. Add google account and check "Google Drive" (possibly a logout/login or reboot is also needed).

You will find your drive in Dolphin -> Places -> Network -> Google Drive.

[Dophin view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QLx94.png)

Reference:
https://pkgs.org/download/kio-gdrive